# Button onclick won't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button, onclick

On my site, when I click the **Begin the Exam** button, some elements are supposed to be shown. However, whenever I click it, the elements are shown and then hidden. **[This is the site](http://gnorybeta.net16.net/al1jan16reg.html)** and this is the code that controls the `onclick()` event :

```
// Display initial question
$("#begin").click(function(){
    $("#quiz").removeClass("hidden");
    $("#intro").addClass("hidden");
    $("#prev").removeClass("hidden");
    $("#next").removeClass("hidden");
    $("#questionnum").removeClass("hidden");

    displayNext();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this as follows;

```
$("#begin").click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();

  $("#quiz, #prev, #next, #questionnum").removeClass("hidden");
  $("#intro").addClass("hidden");

  displayNext();
});
```

Or, just you can modify your "Begin the exam" button for solving this. If you update href attribute like this; `href="javascript:;"`, you can solve this. Because, when your  has empty href attribute, page will be refreshed. You need to prevent this default action or you need to set an useless href attribute to your link.

Answer (score 1):

The `#begin` is an anchor so you have to prevent default action that redirect to the url inside `href` attribute using `e.preventDefault();`, since now the page refresh when you click :

```
$("#begin").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $("#quiz, #prev, #next, #questionnum").removeClass("hidden");
    $("#intro").addClass("hidden");

    displayNext();
});
```

**NOTE :** You could use comma separator `,` for multiple selector.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set it like this:

```
$("#begin").click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
$("#quiz").removeClass("hidden");
$("#intro").addClass("hidden");
 $("#prev").removeClass("hidden");
$("#next").removeClass("hidden");
 $("#questionnum").removeClass("hidden");
 displayNext();

});
```

Comment: While I've been sending mine - others appeared.